# SmartGWT Server File Browser

Tags: java, web-applications, gwt, smartgwt

I have been looking for a SmartGWT example that would show me how to build a File Browser widget that takes the files from the local server's root directory.  The user would be shown the files through the browser which they could then select to perform some processing operations.

So far I have thought of using SmartGWT's *Tree->Data Binding->Load from Local Data* Widget and then grabbing a list of the directories using:

new File("\").listFiles();

My Question is: Is there a better way to do this?  Has someone already thought of this and has an example of their code that I can see?

**PS**: I'm fairly new to GWT and Web Services but fairly competent with Java.  If you believe there is a better way to do this (while still doing this through the web and not using Applets, please tell me).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you want to set this up as a DataSource so you can handle large file systems by incrementally loading tree data.

This is actually built into the Pro edition - there is an included FilesystemDataSource that is present if you inherit the tools module (see [this faq](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=8159#aVisualBuilder)).  It supports all 4 CRUD operations (browse files, add files, remove files, update files).  It can be enabled in server.properties (FilesystemDataSource.enabled:true).

If you prefer to write the server code yourself, use DMI.  See the [QuickStart Guide](http://www.smartclient.com/releases/SmartGWT_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf) chapter on the Server Framework for details.

Finally, if you don't have Pro, the [RestDataSource](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/data/RestDataSource.html) provides a cookbook server integration path (more work than with Pro, but relatively straightforward if you are familiar with servlets, XML/JSON serialization, etc).

Comment: Thanks alot, this should get me started into building what I need.